# Can more than one JavaScript handler register to an event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can more than one JavaScript handler register to an event such as `window.onresize`?
I tried using `+=`, but that had no effect. Only `=` and that obviously replaces any previously assigned events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For IE you can use:
`window.attachEvent('onresize', handler);`

where handler is your handler function.

In all other browsers you can use:
`window.addEventListener('resize', handler);`

Both of these functions can be used multiple times to attach multiple event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple handlers for a single event, but the mechanism to do this is different in different browsers - so it's easier to use a framework to do it:

```
$(document).click(function() { 
  alert('a');
});

$(document).click(function() {
  alert('b');
});
```

Events are fired in the order which they are bound - so in this case, `foo` will be seen before `bar`. You can stop subsequent events from being fired by calling the [stopImmediatePropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29) function with the handler.